# Why isn't MSWindows product code kept secure?

Tags: physical

Yesterday I have noticed MSWindows product code on KFC's machines is exposed to the public (photo below).

It might be a mistake but it made me think of something a friend of mine told me once, how he used to go to Internet cafes and copy the product key either from the back of the machine or use a software to retrieve it.

Why wouldn't it be protected even that it cost money?

[image]

Comment: Questions of the form "Why wouldn't supplier X do Y?" are not a good fit here, as you'll need to ask the supplier.

Comment: A few reasons. For one thing, Microsoft makes its money by being the standard. The more people use their software, the harder it is to be a person who doesn't use their software, the more clients they have and products for Windows people buy and the more money they make. That's why they'll often bundle Windows with new hardware; Microsoft will pay to have their O/S on that hardware. In fact, even without a product key, Windows runs pretty much fine. It'll occasionally complain about the lack of key, and the Desktop background is wonky, but apart from that, fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is an OEM product code, which means that it's baked into the firmware somewhere. Copying the code won't allow you to install Windows on another machine, so there's no real need to secure it by removing the sticker.

Comment: Actually OEM code can be installed on the machine from same serie. But with high probability will not pass the MS test